# If $gcd(n,m)=1$ and $x\equiv y(mod\phi(m))$ then $n^{x}\equiv n^{y}(modm)$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I am trying to prove that if  $gcd(n,m)=1$ and $x\equiv y(mod\phi(m))$ then $n^{x}\equiv n^{y}(modm)$.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), if $\gcd(n,m)=1$ then $n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod m$

Comment: See the [Theorem & Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the linked dupe (using $\,e=\phi(m))\,$ & Euler's Theorem)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\text{gcd}(n,m)=1\implies n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1(\text{ mod  } m)$.

Now, $x\equiv y(\text{ mod }\phi(m))\implies x=y+k\phi(m)$ for some integer $k$.

Now, $$n^x=n^{y+k\phi(m)}=n^y\cdot \big(n^{\phi(m)}\big)^k\equiv n^y\cdot (1)^k=n^y(\text{ mod } m).$$

Comment: Thank you very much!